# Hide column name in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and have two models - Project and ProjectSolutions where Project has many ProjectSolutions. I'm eager loading the data when I query the project details as below:

```
Project.findOne(
    { 
        include: [
            { model: ProjectSolution, as: 'solutions', attributes: { include:['solution'], exclude:['id', 'project_id', 'tblProjectProjectId'] } }
        ],
        where: { project_id: projectID, is_active: true }
    }
)
```

The results returned is as below:

```
{
    "project_id": "project_id_1",
    "name": "Mahendra's demo 1",
    "description": "demo descripition",
    "is_active": true,
    "created_by": "liya",
    "modified_by": null,
    "created_datetime": "2019-04-03T05:38:17.000Z",
    "modified_datetime": null,
    "solutions": [
        {
            "solution": "Document Cloud"
        },
        {
            "solution": "Experience Cloud"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to hide the column name `solution` returned in the `solutions` array as shown below:

```
{
    "project_id": "project_id_1",
    "name": "Mahendra's demo 1",
    "description": "demo descripition",
    "is_active": true,
    "created_by": "liya",
    "modified_by": null,
    "created_datetime": "2019-04-03T05:38:17.000Z",
    "modified_datetime": null,
    "solutions": [
        "Document Cloud",
        "Experience Cloud"
    ]
}
```

I referred the docs but couldn't find how to achieve this. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure but there isn't the way in sequelize. what about try to use loop to make new solutions array?

Comment: @kkangi Did think of that but that would be not optimal as I use a similar query in the project list as well. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: as @kkangil pointed, Sequelize does not support that. You need to do your mapping after getting the result.

Comment: I agree @kkangil